# Exception in AllJoyn studio demo code in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windowsiot, alljoyn

I am a complete newbie to the AllJoyn Windows implementation. I was trying out the Toaster example [AllJoyn Studio VS Extension sample](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/Docs/AllJoynStudio) to understand the AllJoyn Producer Consumer capabilities as bundled with Windows 10. First of all the code in that sample link is not compatible with the latest AllJoyn library [Alljoyn Studio Watcher class not generated](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e78796f3-db12-4013-ae7f-42c4db6e3d51/alljoyn-studio-watcher-class-not-generated?forum=WindowsIoT). Hence I used the code from the AllJoyn Producer and Consumer experiences samples provided as a part of the  [Windows-Universal-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AllJoyn/ProducerExperiences) and modified it to adapt the Toaster example. While I can build the solution fine, but I am encountering a very esoteric runtime error when I am trying to create the instance of the Watcher class. The code where the the error is happening is:

```
    private AllJoynBusAttachment toasterBusAttachment;
    private DeviceWatcher watcher;
    private ToasterConsumer consumer;

    public ToasterConsumerLib()
    {
        toasterBusAttachment = new AllJoynBusAttachment();
        // This is the error line 
          watcher = AllJoynBusAttachment.GetWatcher(new List<string> { 
          "org.alljoyn.example.Toaster" }); 
        watcher.Added += Watcher_Added;
        watcher.Start();

    }
```

The error details is as follows: **An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in ToasterSample.exe but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.__ComObject' to type 'Windows.Devices.AllJoyn.IAllJoynBusAttachmentStatics'.**

My platform is

- Windows 10 Anniversary Edition(10.0, Build 14393) with all latest updates
- Visual Studio 2015 with the AllJoyn Studio Extension

I am not very sure on how should I go about trying to troubleshoot this issue. Any pointers in the right direction will be very helpful.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue by this small piece of code. How did you modify Producer and Consumer experiences samples?

Comment: I did not modify the code from the Producer Consumer experience samples. I was writing a small POC to test the Toaster sample and only used the new API to get a reference to the Watcher object from the consumer experience sample. I do realize that my original post hints at the fact that I have adapted the producer consumer experience sample code but that was not correctly worded.

Comment: If you can provide complete code that produced this issue I can do more test.